# Rails has_one belongs_to Routing and form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for, belongs-to, has-one

So I have two models

```
class First < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :story
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :first
end
```

I want to create a new first, which is associated with a story. Each story can only have one first. I'm trying to use this as my form_for

```
<%= form_for ([@story, @first]) do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :message %><br/>
 <%= f.text_field :message %><br/>
 <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

However, I don't know how to set this up in my routes to cater for this. At the moment, I get a "undefined method story_firsts_path" error. Here is my firsts controller

```
class FirstsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @story = Story.new
    @first = @story.build_first
  end
end
```

Am I way off here or am I somewhat on the right track?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use nested routes to define story and first. Like this:

```
resources :stories do
  resources :firsts
end
```

Comment: Singular resource would be sufficient. His controller is incorrect as well.